# Народно-поэтический или народнопоэтический?

Tags: орфография, слитно-дефис

В различных редакциях Розенталя, которые представлены в интернете, имеются варианты как слитного, так и дефисного написания.

Вопрос, собственно, возник из-за разногласия между мной и преподавателем, утверждавшим, что «слово "народнопоэтический" состоит из словосочетания "народная поэзия" и поэтому пишется не через дефис» (цитируется со слов учителя).

Comment: gramota.ru/biblio/research/slovari-norm/pril3

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: ***народно-поэтический***, дефисное написание.

И Розенталь тут ни при чем, так как форма написания слов может объясняться в правилах, но **регламентируется она только словарями**.

**НАРОДНО-ПОЭТИЧЕСКИЙ**,  =Фольклорный.  (Большой толковый словарь русского языка.Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.  Публикуется в авторской редакции 2014 года).

**Но выбор дефисной формы нужно объяснить.**

Согласно общему принципу написания сложных прилагательных, выбор формы письма зависит от **исходного сочетания,** например: ***народная поэзия — народнопоэтический, народный поэтический — народно-поэтический.***

А теперь рассмотрим **сочетаемость** этого слова.

*Народнопоэтический* и *народно-поэтический* могут сочетаться со словом ***язык***, тогда мы получаем: язык народной поэзии — *народнопоэтический язык*; народный поэтический язык — народно-поэтический язык. Здесь варианты **равноправны.**

Но рассмотрим **другие сочетания**, например: ***народно-поэтическое творчество.***

Здесь уже **дефисное написание не подходит**. Как сказать: творчество народной поэзии? Это неверно,  правильно: народное поэтическое (народно-поэтическое) творчество, то есть поэтическое творчество народа.

Поэтому за основу взят **универсальный термин с дефисным написанием,  который сочетается со всеми словами:** *народно-поэтический — это народный поэтический*.

Comment: А что Вы думаете по поводу написания слова "естественно-научный"?

Comment: В словаре дано слитное написание: ЕСТЕСТВЕННОНАУЧНЫЙ, -ая, -ое. Относящийся к естественным наукам (геологии, биологии, астрономии, географии, физике и т.п.). В справочнике  РАН (2012) слово пишется через дефис. Думаю, что исправление сделано корректно, вариант "естественный научный" здесь не подходит.

Comment: Но возможен ли мой вариант как таковой? Потому что где-то корректно использовать написание через дефис, а где-то – слитно.

Comment: Нет, вариант некорректен. В этой теме нередко делаются изменения, поэтому нужен постоянный контроль по словарям РАН, а это Грамота.ру. Просто изменения не успевают вносить, не знают о них. Я, к примеру, всегда проверяю написание сложных прилагательных по этому словарю. Словарь - это как ЗАКОН. Его могут изменить, но подчиняться ему нужно обязательно, причем именно в последней редакции.

Comment: Грамота.ру утверждает, что корректно дефисное написание.

Comment: Задайте вопрос Грамоте.ру. Или они утверждают неправильно, или в словаре на их сайте ошибка. Пусть что-нибудь исправляют .http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=естественнонаучный&all=x

Comment: Разумеется, если в справочнике 2012 года указано дефисное написание, то все пишут через дефис. Например:  естественно-научные  методы, специальности, музеи. В принципе "естественный" - это еще и связанный с изучением природы и её законов. Тогда можно сказать, что естественно-научные методы - это естественные научные методы, то есть научные методы, основанные на природных явлениях, связанные с природой. Кроме того, надо учитывать, что слитное написание подобных терминов неудобно для прочтения. Поэтому на Грамоте.ру нужно, скорее всего, подправить словарь.

Answer (score 0):

Если прилагательное образовано от словосочетания, то оно пишется **слитно**: ***железная дорога - железнодорожный***.

***Народнопоэтический*** (народная поэзия) - слитное написание зафиксировано в "Орфографическом словаре" п/р С.Г. Бархударова, С.И. Ожегова и А.Б. Шапиро.

***Естественнонаучный***(естественные науки) - слитное написание зафиксировано в "Орфографическом словаре" п/р С.Г. Бархударова, С.И. Ожегова и А.Б. Шапиро.

Comment: Из словаря Кузнецова (2014) НАРОДНО-ПОЭТИЧЕСКИЙ, -ая, -ое. =Фольклорный. Н-ое творчество. Н-ая традиция.  http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=народно-поэтический

Comment: Екатерина, нет ничего нелепого и странного. Прочитайте статью, пройдясь по ссылке,  которую я привел под вопросом. В интернете есть также две статьи: Кто в доме хозяин? И ответ Букчиной на эту статью.

Answer (score 0):

Вот что пишет Грамота.ру

Дефисное написание в словаре, о котором Вы говорите, – не опечатка. Дело в том, что авторы словаря (Б. З. Букчина, Л. П. Калакуцкая) предлагают особый (надо признать, весьма разумный) подход к решению вопросов слитного / дефисного написания сложных имен прилагательных (не случайно поэтому книга носит подзаголовок «Опыт словаря-справочника»). Расскажем об этом подходе подробнее.

Как известно, согласно действующим «Правилам русской орфографии и пунктуации» 1956 года, основной критерий слитного / дефисного написания прилагательных – отношение между основами: слитно пишутся прилагательные, образованные от двух слов, по своему значению подчиненных одно другому (железнодорожный – от железная дорога), через дефис пишутся прилагательные, образованные из двух или более основ, обозначающих равноправные понятия (беспроцентно-выигрышный). Однако эти правила очень часто нарушаются – причем не только и не столько из-за незнания их пишущими, сколько из-за того, что не всегда удается определить, какие отношения существуют между мотивирующими словами – подчинение или сочинение (особенно это касается слов, относящихся к разным областям науки, техники, культуры). Но и тогда, когда эти отношения ясны, дефисных написаний вместо требуемых правилами слитных слишком много, чтобы можно было списать это только на безграмотность (тем более учитывая, что картотека собиралась авторами в 1970-е – 80-е, когда за грамотной устной и письменной речью следили куда тщательнее, чем сейчас).

Далее цитируем предисловие к словарю: «Авторы настоящего Словаря пытались выяснить, что же заставляет упорно писать через дефис, вопреки требованиям "Правил", некоторые сложные прилагательные. Лингвистическим основанием для этого авторы считают формально выраженную грамматическую самостоятельность первой части сложного прилагательного. ...Первая часть имеет суффиксы, характеризующие ее как прилагательное».

Иными словами: наличие в первой части суффикса прилагательного или причастия влияет на замену слитного написания дефисным. Поэтому пишут естественно-научный (хотя слово образовано от сочетания естественные науки), лечебно-физкультурный  и т. д.

Обнаруженную орфографическую тенденцию авторы словаря предложили закрепить в виде правил, которые и легли в основу рекомендаций издания. Одно из них гласит: пишутся через дефис сложные имена прилагательные, образованные из двух и более основ, имеющие в этих основах суффиксы прилагательных (или причастий). Вот почему в словаре рекомендуется писать слово спинно-мозговой через дефис: в первой части есть суффикс прилагательного -н-.

Некоторые из написаний, обусловленных действием данной орфографической тенденции, утвердились в современной письменной речи и фиксируются большинством словарей. Таковы уже упоминавшиеся выше прилагательные естественно-научный и лечебно-физкультурный – сегодня нормативно дефисное написание этих слов (да, де-юре оно не соответствует правилам правописания, но объясняется это тем, что во многом устарели сами правила). Однако написание большинства сложных прилагательных по-прежнему основывается на «Правилах» 1956 года – в том числе и слова спинномозговой, которое, согласно правилам, следует писать слитно (слитное написание этого слова фиксируют практически все словари, в том числе «Русский орфографический словарь» РАН – самый полный на сегодняшний день орфографический справочник).

Answer (score 0):

Лично я не вижу никаких причин для того, чтобы менять  правила 1956 года. Не стоит считать, что во всем виноваты формальные правила, в которых будто бы обнаружились какие-то ошибки и неточности.

**Как выбирается форма** написания  для сложных прилагательных?

1) **Обобщенная семантика**  должна считываться с формы слова, форманты НАРОДНО-, ЕСТЕСТВЕННО- — это имеющие отношение к народу, к изучению природы.

2) Определяется и учитывается **способ словообразования**.  Многие термины можно вывести как из словосочетания (слитное написание), так и из основ двух прилагательных (дефисное написание).

3) Учитываются д**ругие факторы**. Например, многосложные термины со слитным написанием бывают **неудобны для чтения**, и их просто пишут через дефис, хотя это чистое сложение "наречие + прилагательное".

4) Надо учитывать **уже сложившиеся традиции** написания, а это ***народно-поэтический, естественно-научный.***

С учетом всего сказанного надо выбрать **удобную и обоснованную форму письма для каждого термина и остановиться на ней,** а не метаться от одной формы к другой, меняя их **в словаре** чуть ли не каждый год.

И тогда всё будет в порядке, и всё будет по правилам. Только правила эти (**вернее, обоснования**)   надо четко обозначить, чтобы люди их понимали и пользовались ими разумно.

Comment: Вы, кто хорошо разбирается в вопросах русского языка, должны понимать, что не все так просто. Лингвисты все лишь наблюдают за практикой письма, и уже на основании этого создабт правила, кодифицируют тот или иной вариант. А просто взят и узоконить тот или иной вариант, потому что он кажется удобным нельзя.

Comment: И удобный доя кого? Что бы ни делали лингвисты, все равно найдуться сторонники того или иного варианта. И опять будут: возмущение, недовольство.

Comment: Серж, я вижу, как лингвисты "наблюдают" за практикой письма. Весь Нацкорпус пишет "естественно-научный" (это уже сложившаяся традиция), связь с "естественными науками" слишком конкретна, чтобы ее обозначать на письме, удобство чтения слова, в котором 18 букв, тоже не на последнем месте. И вот "учитывая" все эти факторы, наши лингвисты объявляют правильным слитное написание, когда  в их же справочнике РАН (2012)  зафиксировано раздельное письмо. "Хорошее" получилось наблюдение за письменной практикой.

Comment: @ Sharon, В справочнике РАН дефисное написание. Какие такие лингвисты объявляют правильным слитное написание?

Comment: Так в словаре Кузнецова дается слитное написание, а словарь - это закон. Это не то, что пример из справочника, а нечто гораздо более ответственное. А Грамота предлагает именно этот словарь. С одним словом разобраться не могут.  Такие слова нужно подробно, а не давать коротенький ответ (слитно или раздельно). Вот у них надо спросить, почему в словаре слово пишется слитно и почему его надо писать через дефис. А то у каждого свой подход, свое авторское видение, а для простейшей задачи не могут предложить однозначного и окончательного решения. А для пользователей это важный практический вопрос.

Comment: Sharon, Грамота в спорных случаях как раз предлагает ориентироваться на орфографический словарь, а не на Кузнецова.

Comment: Тогда пусть отредактируют словарь Кузнецова, чтобы он не вводил людей в заблуждение. Этот словарь весьма значимый, так как выбор формы письма часто зависит от значения слова, а оно указано в толковом словаре. В орфографическом словаре объяснений нет, и ситуация, о которой рассказывает автор вопроса,  очень показательна: разные формы письма, отсутствие объяснений и разногласия между учителем и учеником в результате. А лингвисты к этому вроде бы отношения не имеют, у них свои проблемы

Comment: Sharon, на портале Грамоты.ру множество вопросов, связанных с разногласием данных словарей. И на все вопросы они отвечают, что надо ориентироваться на орфографический словарь.

Comment: Что касается выбора той или формы в зависимости от смысла, в настоящее время, как пишет Букчина, этот принцип не выдерживается. Не выдерживался он и тогда. Даже "народно-хозяйственный" тогда уже испытывало колебания. В разных изданиях словарей оно писалось то через дефис, то слитно.

Comment: Почитайте "Кто в доме хозяин?" И ответ Букчиной на эту статью.

Comment: Серж, честно говоря, у меня нет особенного желания читать Букчину, достаточно того, что я прочитала ее биографию Эти люди занимались и занимаются не тем, чем надо.  Семантический принцип русского письма - это, можно сказать, наша гордость, наше национальное достояние. А они стремятся его реформировать, упростить и   свести к формализму. Они несколько раз пытались провести свои реформы в открытую, а теперь занимаются этим исподтишка. Возможно, они не чувствуют и не понимают русского языка или что-то ещё  возможно.

Comment: Но они расшатывают нашу систему письма, вместо того чтобы изучать ее и  нести людям. Какой толк в том, что у них всё "колеблется", в том, что они 60-70 лет изучают правописание нескольких слов, но так и не могут догадаться, почему они так пишутся. Нет, это не те лингвисты, которые вызывают во мне уважение. И надеюсь я только на новых людей, которые сменят это поколение.