# Устно(-)поэтический — слитно или через дефис?

Tags: орфография, прилагательные, слитно-дефис

Здесь уже обсуждался вопрос о правописании прилагательного "народно-поэтический".
А слово *устнопоэтический/устно-поэтический* как пишется? В словарях его нет.
На практике (в научных статьях, монографиях) чаще всего встречается вариант слитного написания. Как быть в таком случае?

Answer (score 2):

В словаре Букчиной "Слитно или раздельно" дано дефисное написание.
https://www.endic.ru/bukchina/Ustno-poeticheskij-27590.html
Почему? Лопатин объясняет:

> В правиле 1956 года противопоставляется написание прилагательных с
>   равноправным отношением частей сложного слова (такие сложные слова
>   полагается писать через дефис) и с неравноправным, подчинительным
>   отношением частей (их полагается писать слитно). Но есть множество
>   слов, которые не подчиняются этому правилу, пишутся иначе. Даже в
>   самих правилах 1956 года приведено слово глухонемой в слитном
>   написании. В академическом "Орфографическом словаре русского языка"
>   (1974 года и последующие издания) мы видим написания: нефтегазовый,
>   газопаровой, пароводяной, водовоздушный, буровзрывной. В этих сложных
>   словах явно равноправное соотношение основ, но они пишутся вопреки
>   действующему правилу слитно. В то же время есть много примеров, когда
>   при подчинительном отношении частей прилагательные пишутся вопреки
>   правилу через дефис: буржуазно-демократический (ср. буржуазная
>   демократия), парашютно-десантный, жилищно-кооперативный,
>   государственно-монополистический, научно-исследовательский,
>   научно-фантастический, ракетно-технический, гражданско-правовой,
>   стрелково-спортивный, из более новых слов - ядерно-энергетический,
>   партийно-номенклатурный и др. Если большой ряд слов, включающий
>   десятки образований, не подчиняется правилу, значит, правило это не
>   действует. Его следует заменить другим правилом, найти какой-то другой
>   критерий разграничения слитных и дефисных написаний сложных имен
>   прилагательных. В новом своде предлагается такой критерий: если в
>   первой части слова есть суффикс имени прилагательного (суффикс -н-,
>   -ов- или -ск-), то такое сложное прилагательное надо писать через дефис - независимо от того, равноправное в нем или неравноправное
>   соотношение частей. Иными словами, смысловой критерий выбора написания
>   заменяется формально-грамматическим.

http://lingvotech.com/r-russkayaorfograf
https://slovar.wikireading.ru/3477695

Answer (score 1):

1) Действительно, **в словарях на Грамоте-ру** слово ***устно-поэтический*** "скромно" отсутствует. Или его вообще нет, или не знают, как его писать.

В текстах встречалось и слитное написание, но **дефисное** используется чаще, например:
[https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/rus_orthography/93583/устно](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/rus_orthography/93583/%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE)

2) **Как объяснить?** Я бы не стала пользоваться методом, который предлагает Лопатин. К примеру, у него на сайте до сих  присутствуют две формы письма:

Орфографический словарь: ***естественно-научный***.

Большой толковый словарь: ***ЕСТЕСТВЕННОНАУЧНЫЙ***, . Относящийся к естественным наукам (геологии, биологии, астрономии, географии, физике и т.п.).

Вот к чему приводит **формально-грамматический критерий.** И вообще непонятно, почему орфография (наука прикладная) руководит грамматикой, наукой вполне серьезной и самостоятельной. Или они существуют в параллельных реальностях?

3) **Помочь ему что ли?**

"Правило" будет такое:

Если сложное слово в **реально существующих** сочетаниях  **нельзя разделить на два прилагательных**, то оно должно писаться только слитно, например:

***Естественнонаучные   методы*** — естественные научные методы? Нет, так не говорят (научные методы не определяются как естественные), поэтому пишем только слитно. Да и  вообще это научный термин, который проверяется по толковому словарю.

***Устно-поэтическое творчество*** — устное поэтическое творчество. Дефисное написание допускается, и это единственный вариант, так как устная поэзия и устно-поэтическое творчество — это примерно одно и то же.

4) **Примечание** (сравнение методов)

**Если сравнить "наши правила",** то есть принципиальная **разница**: у Лопатина дефисное сложное прилагательное **складывается** из основ прилагательных (поэтому он формально ориентируется на их суффиксы), а у меня, напротив, сложное прилагательное **разлагается** на два прилагательных.

Причем разлагается обязательно **в реальных словосочетаниях:** устно-поэтическое творчество — устное поэтическое творчество.

Здесь сочинительная связь двух неоднородных прилагательных, при этом **смысл сочетания сохраняется**. Это, так сказать, **семантическая проверка** правильного выбора формы слова.

5) А это обсуждение формы написания другого слова (очень длинное)

[Народно-поэтический или народнопоэтический?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/449785/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)